# Google Custom Search API: cannot change quota in the Console

Tags: google-api

I have a valid billing configuration for my Google Custom Search API. This should allow me to make up to 10,000 queries per day. In Developers Console at the APIs > Custom Search API > Quota page I try to change the current "1,000 requests/day" to 5000. After applying the change I can see the new value WHILE I'm on the Quota page. But after switching to another page and back I see the old "1,000 requests/day". Decreasing the value (to 900) neither works.

Naively trying to query the API more than 1000 times gives me "Daily Limit Exceeded" meaning the limit is really NOT applied.

Quota modification worked for me some month ago but now it doesn't. What can be the reason?

Comment: Exact same problem here... it is really frustrating. Please let us know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug with the **new** console.
It works if you set the quota in the previous generation console. 
To access it from the new console:

APIs & auth -> APIs -> Custom Search API -> Reports

Comment: what is the url of previous generation console? I have the same problem.